# Deinterleaving of a 2-channel WAV file into two text files containing raw data

Tags: c

I have an assignment based on the above stated problem. The sampling frequency and size per sample would be known in the problem. I just need an idea about the kind of coding that would be required for this.

Comment: You're going to have to expand on your question significantly for it not to get closed. Do you have any code? Any specific problem? Any O/S in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sampling frequency is irrelevant for this, but the size per sample (typically 8 or 16 bit per channel per sample) decides which pointer-size you need to use, so here the example of 8 bit per channel:

```
char* reader = begin; // interleaved
char* left = malloc(numsamples); // de-interleaved
char* right = malloc(numsamples);
while(reader<end) {
    *left = *reader;
    ++left;
    ++reader;
    *right = *reader;
    ++right;
    ++reader;
}
```

To do the same for 2 channel 16 bit interleaved audio you just declare all 3 buffers as `short*` and instead `malloc(numsamples*2)`

Comment: I think i got a fair bit of idea about what needs to be done. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: sure thing! accept and/or upvote answers if you like them (esp mine ;-) )

Answer (score 4):

Use a file format spec such as [this one](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) to see how to read the file header, determining sample rate, bit rate etc.

```
The canonical WAVE format starts with the RIFF header:

0         4   ChunkID          Contains the letters "RIFF" in ASCII form
                               (0x52494646 big-endian form).
4         4   ChunkSize        36 + SubChunk2Size, or more precisely:
                               4 + (8 + SubChunk1Size) + (8 + SubChunk2Size)
                               This is the size of the rest of the chunk 
                               following this number.  This is the size of the 
                               entire file in bytes minus 8 bytes for the
                               two fields not included in this count:
                               ChunkID and ChunkSize.
8         4   Format           Contains the letters "WAVE"
                               (0x57415645 big-endian form).

The "WAVE" format consists of two subchunks: "fmt " and "data":
The "fmt " subchunk describes the sound data's format:

12        4   Subchunk1ID      Contains the letters "fmt "
                               (0x666d7420 big-endian form).
16        4   Subchunk1Size    16 for PCM.  This is the size of the
                               rest of the Subchunk which follows this number.
20        2   AudioFormat      PCM = 1 (i.e. Linear quantization)
                               Values other than 1 indicate some 
                               form of compression.
22        2   NumChannels      Mono = 1, Stereo = 2, etc.
24        4   SampleRate       8000, 44100, etc.
28        4   ByteRate         == SampleRate * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
32        2   BlockAlign       == NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
                               The number of bytes for one sample including
                               all channels. I wonder what happens when
                               this number isn't an integer?
34        2   BitsPerSample    8 bits = 8, 16 bits = 16, etc.
          2   ExtraParamSize   if PCM, then doesn't exist
          X   ExtraParams      space for extra parameters

The "data" subchunk contains the size of the data and the actual sound:

36        4   Subchunk2ID      Contains the letters "data"
                               (0x64617461 big-endian form).
40        4   Subchunk2Size    == NumSamples * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
                               This is the number of bytes in the data.
                               You can also think of this as the size
                               of the read of the subchunk following this 
                               number.
44        *   Data             The actual sound data.
```

After that, you'll find raw pcm data, interleaved like

```
[sample 1      ][sample 2      ]
[s1,ch1][s1,ch2][s2,ch1][s2,ch2]
```

You could open a text file per sample in write, binary mode, then loop over the audio data, reading the bytes for a single sample/channel then using `fprintf` or `fwrite` to write them to the correct file.

Comment: No link-only answers please

Comment: I don't understand.  There seems to be sufficient content in my answer to help the poster towards solving his homework problem.  My answer seems equivalent to unwind's but goes slightly further by also hinting at how to find audio data inside a WAV file.  Can you explain why you find the link objectionable please?

Comment: Without the link, there are key parts missing, I believe. For example, the `.wav` file format. Can you copy out the interesting parts here?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've loaded the WAV data into memory, all you need to do is:

1. Open the two output files (using `fopen()`).
2. Loop over the sample data, and for each sample:

   - Put the left channel's value in the first file
   - Put the right channel's value in the second file
3. Close the files.