# Copying specific data from a source buffer to several target buffers

Tags: c

I have a source buffer which i declared using malloc and i have used fread to read into the buffer some data from a big file. Now I want to separate out alternate chunks of data (say 2 bytes each) from this source buffer into two target buffers. This problem can be extrapolated to copying every nth chunk to n number of target buffers. I need help in the form of a sample code for the simplest case of two target buffers. This is what I thought about which I am quite sure isn't the right thing.

```
int totsamples = 256*2*2;
int *sbuff = malloc(totsamples);
int *tbuff1 = malloc(totsamples/2);
int *tbuff2 = malloc(totsamples/2);
elements = fread(sbuff, 2, 256*2, fs);
for(i = 0; i<256; i++)
{
  tbuff1[i] = sbuff[i*2];
  tbuff2[i] = sbuff[(i*2) + 1];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I am afraid unless you try something and post what you have done, no one will be willing to help you out. The best way is for you to try a sample and then ask your doubt about the more finer details of the problem.

Comment: I have added the code which I could think of. Now can you help me out?

Comment: @vaibh24 did you try your sample code? As far as can be said from such partial code, it looks ok... Maybe update it to be a function, and tell what you'd expect the function to do, and hwo that is different from what your code actually does.

Comment: Are you deinterleaving 2-channel 16 bit audio? Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748191/deinterleaving-of-a-2-channel-wav-file-into-two-text-files-containing-raw-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will give you and idea:

```
for(i = 0; i<256; i++)
{
  tbuff1[2*i+0] = sbuff[i*4+0];
  tbuff1[2*i+1] = sbuff[i*4+1];
  tbuff2[2*i+0] = sbuff[i*4+2];
  tbuff2[2*i+1] = sbuff[i*4+3];
}
```

Note: Above code is wrong with respect to your `malloc()` parameters, as it is unclear what your `totsamples` means, so fix something before using...

Another note: If you want longer than 2 items long chunk, it starts to make sense to use `memcpy` to do the copying.

Suggestion: Use constants instead of magic numbers, such as `const int SAMPLES=256;`. Also I'm not sure, but it appears you think size of `int` is 2?  Don't, instead use `sizeof(int)` etc (and size of `int` is rarely 2, btw).

Hmm... Are you actually trying to optimize things by copying bytes using integers to copy 4 bytes at a time? [**Don't!** "Premature optimization is root of all evil"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). You may consider that later, after you code works otherwise, but first create a working non-hacky version, and doubly so, if you need to ask how to do even that, like here...